# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'unknown error: arguments[0].click is not a function while trying to click svg element using ChromeDriver Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, svg, electron, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate the control of an image element "svg" which has 12 selectable parts inside (with "path" tag).

In all my electron-angular application I have to use js actions with Selenium in order to click on buttons or other UI elements. Selenium Click function or Actions class does not work for me in this application.

So, when I try to click on one of the "svg" element:

```
 IWebElement patientIllustration = electron.driver.FindElement(By.Id("patientIllustration"));
 IWebElement shadow = (IWebElement)jse.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", patientIllustration);
 IWebElement body = shadow.FindElement(By.Id("adult_vascular"));
 IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> parts = body.FindElements(By.TagName("path"));
 IWebElement bodyPart = parts.ElementAt(0); 

 jse.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", bodyPart);
 jse.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", bodyPart);
```

I get the following error:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'unknown error: arguments[0].click is not a function
>     (Session info: content shell=)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36 (7361dbe5ac927be4276ec7da1d3548c4f22343a0),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)'

I have also tried clicking on bodyPart element with Click() method and with Actions class. But it does nothing. These two possibilities does not work for any element in my app.

Does anyone have any other idea to try?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
jse.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", bodyPart);
```

can you try this.

```
jse.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", bodyPart);
```

Comment: Ok. Sorry for that, I've changed it but the exception remains. Besides, I've noticed that bodyPart element has the properties "Displayed" and "Enabled" to true.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'unknown error: arguments[0].click is not a function 
 (Session info: content shell=) 
 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36 
 (7361dbe5ac927be4276ec7da1d3548c4f22343a0),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to communicate with the **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.36*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.36*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.36/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v63-65**

- Possibly you are using the latest *Chrome Browser* i.e. *chrome= 73.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v73.0.3683.68*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/73.0.3683.68/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 73**

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver v2.36* and the *Chrome Browser v73.0*

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Upgrade *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v73*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/73.0.3683.68/notes.txt))
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: My application under test is build with electron 2.0.3. So, I download the chromedriver from https://github.com/electron/electron/releases. So i don't think there are incompatibilities because other buttons work with js click action (Selenium actions are useless in my application, don't know why either)... just the svg parts element (inside a shadow tag) throws the exception